# How to sort hasMany items in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have this structure:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('board', {path: '/board'}, function() {
        this.route('new', {path: '/new'});
        this.route('show', {path: '/show/:board_id'});
    });
});

App.Board = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    initialAmount: DS.attr('number'),
    initialDate: DS.attr('date'),
    boardItems: DS.hasMany('BoardItem'),
    _csrf: DS.attr()
});

App.BoardItem = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    income: DS.attr('number'),
    outcome: DS.attr('number'),
    date: DS.attr('date'),
    itemType: DS.attr('string'),
    board: DS.belongsTo('Board')
});

App.BoardShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('board', params.board_id).sort();
    }
});
```

and in the view, I list the board items like that:

```
{{#each boardItems}}
```

what I'm trying to do is sorting the boardItems by date, and I can't find a way of doing it...
any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create a computed property in the controller behind the view

### Controller

```
App.BoardShowController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  sortedBoardItems: function(){
    return this.get('boardItems').sortBy('date');
  }.property('boardItems.@each.date')
});
```

### Template

```
{{#each sortedBoardItems}}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!
can you please explain this part:

    .property('boardItems.@each.date')

Comment: yeah, each time a new item is added to `boardItems` or one if the `date` field changes (using proper setters) on any of the `boardItems` it will recalculate the property.

Comment: Suppose you want the `boardItems` to be sorted that way every time the `board` is used in the app...would it be a sin to define the `sortedBoardItems` in the model?

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the `{{#each}}...{{/each}}` loop with a `{{render}}` helper and do the sorting in the controller:

#### Controller:

```
App.BoardItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['date'],
  sortAscending: false // newest first
});
```

#### Template:

```
{{#render "boardItems" boardItems}}
  {{#each arrangedContent}}
     Title: {{title}}
     ...
  {{/each}}
{{/render}}
```

Using a computed property for doing the sorting will result in completely recomputing the sorted array, each time the `boardItems` change. This is not the case with the `arrangedContent` approach described here.

Comment: arrayController is being depreciated